# How To crop Image using ajax, jQuery in Codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I see Lot's of image Crop example But i'm not find like what's i want. So i post in Stackoverflow.

A complete script in Codeigniter FrameWork as view as like
1. Click upload and select .jpg/.png file
2. auto upload in server and Show like

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTtO5.png`
3. After upload User crop Profile Pic preDifiend Size.
4. and save in my DB.

I'm unable to ajax. Plz.. If you have complete this Provide me.

Ebrahim Khalil

Comment: Working for me: https://www.tutsmake.com/crop-and-save-image-using-jquery-coppie-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) Plugin, Check out their PHP cropping example. 
Basically what happens when you select are to crop, It will be saved in X,Y for co-ordinates and H,W for height and width.

Codeigniter's image_lib gives simple way to crop or resize image. Read the docs for that ..

My code Snippet :

```
        //crop it
        $data['x'] = $this->input->post('x');
        $data['y'] = $this->input->post('y');
        $data['w'] = $this->input->post('w');
        $data['h'] = $this->input->post('h');

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        //$path =  'uploads/apache.jpg';
        $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/'.$data['user_data']['img_link']; //http://localhost/resume/uploads/apache.jpg
       // $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        //$config['new_image'] = './uploads/new_image.jpg';
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width']  = $data['w'];
        $config['height'] = $data['h'];
        $config['x_axis'] = $data['x'];
        $config['y_axis'] = $data['y'];

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        if(!$this->image_lib->crop())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }  
        redirect('profile');
```

Here original Uploaded image is cropped , you can also create new image. Just make create_thumb = true for that.

Comment: Thanks. I had same problem.